# How to create a code where an integer is converted to three digets and added to a string

Tags: javascript

I want to create a code where an integer is converted to three digits and added to a string.

Something like this:

```
let 
value = String. Format("tstexa%03d",Script.Index);
return value;
Where Script. Index is an integer.
```

Comment: The description of the one-and-only `[script]` Tag you added to your question says _"DON'T USE THIS TAG! Every SO question is about scripts one way or another. Use appropriate tags like [bash], [javascript], [google-apps-script] or [python] instead. Your question might not be visible to potential answerers, if you don't use a specific tag. "_: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script

Answer (score 0):

I belive you want the final answer to be "tstexa045" when example Script.Index value is 45

```
let paddedString = Script.Index.toString().padStart(3, '0'); //045
let value = "tstexa" + paddedString;
console.log(value); // example tstexa045
```